# Orbits of the $\operatorname{Aut} (G)$ for $G = (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z) ^k$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

$\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ turns out to be group of invertible $k\times k$ matrices over $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$. It turns out that the problem is equivalent to seeing whether a  $k$ vector with entries in $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ whose gcd is a unit in $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ extendable to a $k\times k$ invertible matrix in $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$. Then every $k$ vector is equivalent to vector $[g, 0 ,0 ,...]$, $g$ belongs to $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ upto units in $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$.

i settled the case for $k = 2$ 
Also if n is a prime the case is settled.
i want a non prime
and if possible what will be the sizes of these orbits?
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show your claim by induction.

You have proved the case $n=2$.
Suppose $n \ge 3, k = (x_1 ,\ldots ,x_n), g' = \gcd(x_1 ,\ldots ,x_{n-1}), g = \gcd(k) = \gcd(g',x_n)$.
Using the induction hypothesis, we know that the vector $(x_1, \ldots ,x_{n-1})$ is equivalent to $(0, \ldots ,0, g')$. 
Then, using the case $n=2$, we know that $(g',x_n)$ is equivalent to $(0,g)$. By padding the matrices as necessary (with the identity), and combining them, you obtain an element of $SL_n(\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z)$ sending $k$ to $(0,\ldots,0,g)$.

Each equivalence class correspond to a gcd modulo $m$, which corresponds to a positive divisor of $m$. For such a divisor $d$, an element of the class $d$ is a vector of the form $d \times k'$ where $k' \in (\Bbb Z/(m/d)\Bbb Z)^n$ and $\gcd(k') = 1$. So the problem boils down to the number $N(n,m)$ of coprime vectors modulo $m$.

Since $m^n = \sum_{d\mid m} N(n,d)$, the Möbius inversion formula gives $N(n,m) = \sum_{d\mid m} \mu(d) (m/d)^n$

Comment: Thanx for help! i understood the proof.

Comment: Thanx for help! i understood the proof. But You are claiming that The  cardinality of orbit of [d,0,0,...] is N(n,m/d)  (Probably is that the thing?)  that  i did not understand . Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @rohit : en element in the orbit of [d,0,0,...] modulo m, has all his coefficients divisible by d, so it is of the form d*an element in the orbit of [1,0,0,...] modulo (m/d). This is a very natural bijection between the orbit of [d,0,0,0,...] modulo m and the orbit of [1,0,0,...] modulo (m/d)

Comment: consider the case for Z /6 Z  and k = 2 . [4,0] comes in orbit of [2,0] due to multiplying it with 2 X 2 matrix left column [5 0] right column  [0,1] , and not with extending [2,0] as [2,0] cant be extended in Z/6Z to an invertible matrix while [2,0] can be extended to an invertible matrix in Z/3Z,  3=6/2.Please explain this phenomenon.

Comment: @rohit : I am really not sure what is there to explain. If you pick a vector (x1..xk) in (Z/nZ)^k, gcd(x1,..,xk,n) = d <=> (x1...xk) is in the Aut((Z/nZ)^k)-orbit of (d,0,...) <=> there is an invertible matrix in Z/nZ such that d * its first column is (x1...xk)